# Better Android Device Detection

Tags: android, browser-detection

I've been looking around for information on detecting Android devices vs iOS devices so that I can either show a link to download an Android or iOS app depending on the device. Every answer I've come across says to look for the "Android" userAgent in the navigator object but after doing a quick print out of that object there is no indication of Android anywhere. I think this must be a feature of newer Android devices. Instead I had to do a bit of a work around by checking to see if the object carries the "Mozilla" tag but not the "Chrome" tag. This seems to work fine, but a Chrome browser was just recently released for Android ICS+ so now what can I check for that differentiates a mobile device from a home computer? At least in this scenario I've set it up (by proggramming subtractively rather than additively) so that if they do happen to have mobile Chrome they see both, but that seems sloppy.

//Update - I found out that HTC devices (and possibly some honeycomb devices) output a false userAgent unless the user is in "mobile View Mode" which can be turned on in their settings.

```
    else if( /(Mozilla)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) !== (/(Chrome)/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
    $('a#iphone_app').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('a#iphone_app').css("display", "none")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to completely hide content. Maybe just make one more prominent then the other. Showing that you support both platforms can be a plus for you.

userAgent on my GNex running Chrome:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
```

userAgent on my MacBook running Crome:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/535.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1055.1 Safari/535.24"
```